# Does UWP support touching with many stylus? How to implement it?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I've implement multi-touch function app using GestureRecognizer. But on Window 10, it only use 1 stylus at the same time. Is there any way to get other pointers (other stylus, hand touch, mouse)?

Comment: As far as I konw, the function will support double tap when you enable [CanBeDoubleTap]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer. But if you need more than one stylus. I don't think this is a reasonable request. Do you mean you want to write two line at the same time? Why you need this?

Comment: Yes, because I'm developing an app for multi stylus but the hardware is not finished yet. So I find some hack or simulation for this.

Comment: Well. I think in UWP this feature is not supported.